# How do I set the background color of a nested cell when using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have two tables.  The outer table is a single column/cell wrapper that I use to paint a gradient background.  I then add a nested/child table which is a single row and has three cells.

```
// set up wrapper table
var wrapperTable = new PdfPTable(1);
wrapperTable .WidthPercentage = 100;

// set up wrapper cell
var wrapperCell = new PdfPCell();
wrapperCell.CellEvent = new GradientBackgroundEvent(writer); // set gradient background
wrapperCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;

// setup nested table
var nestedTable = new PdfPTable(3);
nestedTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
nestedTable.SetWidths(new float[] { 15f, 70f, 15f });

var col1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(myText1, font));
col1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
col1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
col1.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
nestedTable.AddCell(col1);

// this is the cell that I'm interested in - borders work, but no bgcolor
var col2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(myText2, font));
col2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
col2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
col2.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE;            
col2.BorderColor = new BaseColor(204, 204, 204);
col2.BorderWidth = 0.2f;
nestedTable.AddCell(col2);

var col3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(myText3, font));
col3.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
col3.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
col3.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
nestedTable.AddCell(col3);

// add nested table to the wrapper table
wrapperCell.AddElement(nestedTable);
```

I can set the borders for these cells and they paint correctly.  However nothing I've tried (short of removing the gradient background) will allow me to see the background color that I've set on a cell in the nested table.

Here is my code to do the gradient fill.

```
public class GradientBackgroundEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    private PdfWriter w;

    public GradientBackgroundEvent(PdfWriter w)
    {
        this.w = w;
    }

    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        var c1 = new BaseColor(238, 238, 238);
        var c2 = new BaseColor(221, 221, 221);

        PdfShading shading = PdfShading.SimpleAxial(w, position.Left, position.Top, position.Left, position.Bottom, c1, c2);
        PdfShadingPattern pattern = new PdfShadingPattern(shading);
        ShadingColor color = new ShadingColor(pattern);

        PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];

        position.BackgroundColor = color;

        // Fill the rectangle
        cb.Rectangle(position);

    }
}
```

I've tried moving code around and changing the order in which the tables/cells are added but that makes no difference because the PDF is drawn at the end (not as it is constructed).

Judging by my debug - it looks to me like the gradient fill is being painted after the background color for the cell is set and effectively overwriting it.

Does anyone have any ideas about how this can be done?  Maybe I shouldn't be using a table to achieve this?

I've seen some other posts that suggest using a form field is the way to go.  I'd like to avoid this if possible but if it's the only way...

Answer (score 1):

Your background color is getting drawn, unfortunately it is being drawn "under" the gradient background which is why you can't see it. As long as you're only nesting these two tables the simplest solution is probably to just draw your gradient on `PdfPTable.BASECANVAS` instead of `PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS`.

Comment: Pretty much as I thought then.  I'll give what you suggest a go.

Comment: No luck.  After changing to a PdfPTable.BASECANVAS the gradient doesn't show at all.